# Model Form drop-down (select) field not displaying correct rows to choose from

Tags: django, html-select, modelform

I have a `Parent Model` that uses a `Foreign Key` that points to a `Child Model`. In this case, the "Child Model" is called Mstrgensalutationtype (which is really Salutations).

The `Parent Model` is being used to create a `Model Form`

Basically, below is what I get when trying to choose a Salutation Type.

[image]

What I need to see is

```
Mr.
Ms.
Mrs.
Prof.
Dr.
```

Question: What am I doing wrong here?

TIA

**models.py - used as a Child Model**

```
class Mstrgensalutationtype(models.Model):
    saltypeid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    shortval = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    salutationlong = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'MstrGenSalutationType'

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s ' % ( self.shortval )
```

**models.py - used as a Parent Model**

```
class Mstrstorehead(models.Model):
    tenantid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    extrefacctno = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Account Reference No")

[... snip ...]

    contactsalutationid = models.ForeignKey(Mstrgensalutationtype,  models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='contactsalutationid', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Salutation")

[... snip ...]


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'MstrStoreHead'
```

## Update

I made the following change below - but still getting the same problem.

```
class Mstrgensalutationtype(models.Model):
    saltypeid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    shortval = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    salutationlong = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'MstrGenSalutationType'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s ' % ( self.shortval )
```

Comment: What Python version are you using? Also, double-check your indentation - as you have currently posted it, the method is inside the `Meta` class, which is not where it should be (it needs to be in the `Mstrgensalutationtype` class itself).

Comment: @solarissmoke - thanks for the response. Also, plz see changes in the post. Also, I am running with Python: 3.6.3 - Is there something wrong with my Foreign Key definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__unicode__` method is only valid in Python 2 - [it doesn't do anything in Python 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods). You need to use `__str__` instead:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.shortval
```

Note also that the `u` string prefix is redundant in Python 3. All strings are unicode by default.

If you need to support both Python 2 and 3 then use `python_2_unicode_compatible` as described in the link above.

Comment: Yes! That was it! Thanks soooooo much!